# Order an array of objects by descending order of created_at date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have an array of Comment objects retrieved from Mongoid. How do I sort an array by created_at date in descending order.

I have tried the code below:

```
all_comments = []
    all_comments.concat(question_comments).concat(answer_comments).sort_by { |x| -x[:created_at] }
```

I get the following error:

**undefined method `-@' for 2013-08-17 10:34:46 UTC:Time**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [desc](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#desc) method.

```
all_comments.concat(question_comments).concat(answer_comments).desc(:created_at)
```

If the result set is an `Array`, you can use `sort`

```
all_comments.concat(question_comments).concat(answer_comments).sort { |x,y| y.created_at <=> x.created_at }
```

Comment: undefined method `desc' for #<Array:0xb565a7b0>